Why does ubuntu 24.04.1 live suspend and wake properly but does not after full install?
What different reasons could cause Ubuntu 24.04.1 live, suspend and wake properly but does not after full install?
I have tried older versions and am experiencing then same and have never had any problem before.
I suspect it is something in UEFI, my new motherboard, MSI b550-a pro. But I do not understand the difference in running live session and having it installed.

You mention a release (24.04.1) but give no specifics as to what product (Server, Desktop, flavor) and thus kernel used in the live system may differ to what is used post-install, beyond just application of security & other updates on an installed system. Some Ubuntu ISOs include multiple kernel stacks on the ISO, where alternate kernels can be installed/used instead if your hardware is detected as benefiting from those stacks, thus kernel used can differ to the generic kernel that is usually booted on the live system... and that is only one example of difference.

Ubuntu desktop. What about the older versions that I never had problems with till Recent.

Installing the same kernel used for live session made things worse. What else could be wrong?
